# Двойная итерация это очень долго

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Есть массив (DataFrame) данных. По нему идёт двойная итерация.

```
for i in range(0, data.shape[0], 1):
    if data['res1'][i] in range(1, 100, 1): 
        for j in range(0, data.shape[0], 1):
            if data['col1'][j] == data['col1'][i] and data['col2'][j] == data['col2'][i]:
                data['res2'][j] = data['res1'][i]
```

Применить методы `pandas`'a не удалось (сейчас это не обсуждается). Получился некрасивый, плохой, но корректно работающий код. Но всё очень долго.
Пишут, что сложность итерации коллекции = `O(n)`, а у нас двойная итерация, так что `O(n^2)`.

Вопрос: как можно такой ускорить код?

Comment: Вы массив можете преобразовать во что-то древоподобное? Если массив у вас один (т.е. не поступает каждый раз новый массив для одного нового поиска), а поиск идет постоянно, то я бы в этом направлении порыл, чтобы уйти от перебора к методам быстрого поиска. А далее конкретный алгоритм уже от самой задачи и ограничений зависит.

Comment: добавил условия

Comment: где условия-то?

Comment: В начале темы, исправил код вопроса

Comment: Вы хотите решить задачу методами Pandas? (`data` - кажется pandas DataFrame). Или вы хотите решать задачу так будто это у вас словарь массивов и никакого Pandas нет?

Comment: В идеале сделать методами Pandas'a, но так и не смог ничего подобрать. А вообще задача решена, но хотелось бы ускорить обработку приведённой стадии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Линейная сложность. Создаётся словарь значений, затем значения расставляются по местам.

Возможно в Pandas есть подходящие механизмы, это решение сделано "на коленке":

```
d = {
    (t.col1, t.col2): t.res1
    for t in data.itertuples()
    if t.res1 in range(1, 100, 1)
}

data['res2'] = [d.get((t.col1, t.col2), t.res2) for t in data.itertuples()]
```